# Can the idiom "It is high time" be used in formal writing?

Tags: idioms, formality, ielts

Recently I saw  "it is hightime + **subj**. + **past** verb + ..." idiom. Like "It's high time we made some changes around here.". I want to know if it is a good phrase to **start** a **formal** writing (i.e. ielts or toefl writing section) with it or not?

(P.s I would appriciate if you give me some resources to support your respone)

Comment: [Related](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/603360/2085).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, the construction *it is high time* + preterite is perfectly natural and sufficiently formal, usually used in the context of writing that is intended to persuade.

Note that the modifer *high* is not essential: the sentences *it is **time** we **did** something* and *it is **high time** we **did** something* mean pretty much the same thing, except that perhaps the second one adds a little bit of extra emphasis and urgency; see the discussion from [CGEL](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0521431468), below.

**Discussion**

The *Oxford English Dictionary* (OED) defines ***high time*** as

> fully at or (now usually) nearly past the time when something should happen or be done. Frequently with *that* or *to do* something.

The OED has special annotations for its entries that are informal or slang, and there is no such annotation for this entry.

As a recent example of usage, the dictionary lists  *it is **high time** licensing hours **were** trimmed back to no later than 10 pm each night,* from News Rev. Messenger (Austral.) (Nexis)

Other dictionaries give similar definitions. For example, the *Oxford Dictionaries* defines ***it is high time that*** as 'It is past the time when something should have happened or been done' [(here)](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/us/high). While some of the entries just above *high time* have annotation 'informal' (e.g. ***high and mighty***, which is defined as '*informal* Thinking or acting as though one is more important than others'), *high time* does not have any such special annotation. Examples of usage given in that dictionary include

> I would suggest that it is **high time** that government **reconsidered** how it is going to deal with drug pushers, for current methods are expensive, fundamentally ineffective and deny funding in far more needy areas.
>
> I think it is **high time** that elected political representatives **took** a stand against this sort of behaviour.

I should add that the preterite is not essential; other examples of usage include constructions with the present tense, e.g.

> The fact that Ireland hasn't had a national agricultural policy since we joined the EU shows how complacent we have become and it is **high time** that we **become** more pro-active.
>
> The people themselves represent a powerful social resource, and it is **high time** that the federal government **recognizes** this.

Nowhere are there any indications that the construction is informal or problematic in any way. It is a perfectly fine construction to use, even in formal contexts. Some other examples from academic literature:

*It is **high time** we in marketing **paid** even more attention to the criteria for assessing multivariate methods in operational terms.* (from [*Research Issues Underlying Multivariate Methods*](https://books.google.com/books?id=ilD6X4Rllq4C&lpg=PA17&dq=%22it%20is%20high%20time%20we%22&pg=PA17#v=onepage&q=%22it%20is%20high%20time%20we%22&f=false))
*It is **high time** we **turned** this best practice in the direction of domestic violence and its impact on women.* (from [*Rethinking Domestic Violence: The Social Work and Probation Response*](https://books.google.com/books?id=0DSIAgAAQBAJ&lpg=PR9&dq=%22it%20is%20high%20time%20we%22&pg=PR10#v=onepage&q=%22it%20is%20high%20time%20we%22&f=false))
*Yet it is **high time** we **focused** on the issues that arise as we step from traditional international law into the area where nation States are involved in what is known as integration.* (from [*Constitutional Courts and European Integration*](https://books.google.com/books?id=0Agvd714VWUC&lpg=PA203&dq=%22it%20is%20high%20time%20we%22&pg=PA203#v=onepage&q=%22it%20is%20high%20time%20we%22&f=false))
*Bearing in mind the extent and status of testing and the huge costs involved (see Haney, Madaus and Lyons, 1993; Broadfoot, 1994) it is **high time** we **had** an ethical framework for assessment which policy makers, teachers and test developers alike could draw upon.* (from [*Beyond Testing: Towards a Theory of Educational Assessment*](https://books.google.com/books?id=XEGRAgAAQBAJ&lpg=PA144&dq=%22it%20is%20high%20time%20we%22&pg=PA144#v=onepage&q=%22it%20is%20high%20time%20we%22&f=false))

**The role of the past tense (preterite)**

The purpose of the preterite is to make the statement a more **remote possibility.** 
[CGEL](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0521431468) explains this as follows (the phrase *high time* appears in the footnote at the end; CGEL doesn't consider the modifier *high* to be essential):

> **7.2 Modal preterites and irrealis mood**
>
> We use the term **modal preterite** for a preterite that expresses modal rather than temporal meaning, i.e. modal remoteness rather than past time (or backshift). By extension, the  term applies to a clause with a preterite verb-form of this kind:
>
> [25]  i  *Suppose [they **were** in London last week].*                 [ordinary preterite]
>           ii  *Suppose [they **were** in London now/next week].*         [modal preterite]
>
> In [i] we see the primary use of the preterite to locate the situation in past time; in [ii], by contrast, the time is present or future and the preterite serves to imply that their being in London at the time in question is a relatively remote possibility. Example [ii] contrasts with *Suppose they are in London next week,* where the same situation is presented as an open possibility. The modal auxiliaries *could, might, should,* and *would* are found as modal preterites in main as well as subordinate clauses (*It could be over before next 
>   Tuesday; You might have been killed*), but with other verbs modal preterites are restricted to content clauses.
>
> A clause with **irrealis mood** has *were* as verb in construction with a 1st or 3rd person singular subject. In general, modal preterite *was* has irrealis *were* as a somewhat more formal alternant:
>
> [26]  i  *Suppose [she **was** in London now I next week].*        [modal preterite]
>            ii  *Suppose [she **were** in London now I next week].*          [irrealis mood]
>
> Modal preterite and irrealis content clauses are found in the following constructions (see also Ch. 3, §1.7, for uses of irrealis were by some speakers in contexts where it is not an alternant of a modal preterite).
>
> ...
>
> (d) *It **be** time*
>
> [31]  i  ***It is time*** [you **were** in bed].                                                 [present state]
>           ii  ***It is time*** [we **repainted** the house].    [immediate future occurrence]
>
> Here, [i] is straightforwardly counterfactual: "You aren't in bed but you should be". Example [ii] entails that the situation is not yet in progress: "We aren't repainting the house, but should do so". A perfect, as in *It is time you had finished it,* is interpreted as a modally remote version of the present perfect: "You haven't finished but should have done". This construction differs from the others in that it hardly allows an irrealis: *It is time he was/*<sup>?</sup>*were in bed.*<sup>26</sup>
>
> <sup><sup>26</sup>A rare attested example (from a British newspaper) is *It's high time the true cost of the monarchy were pointed out.* Examples are also occasionally found of mandative *should* or a present tense instead of the modal preterite: <sup>%</sup>*Perhaps it is time that the very principle of a public subsidy should be given a thorough examination;* <sup>%</sup>*It is about time we acknowledge the unconscionable fact that international trade benefits no one except the multi-nationals and international financiers.*</sup>

In the above, '<sup>%</sup>' signifies that what follows is grammatical in some dialect(s) only.

Answer (score 2):

high time   [vocabulary.com](https://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/high%20time) idiom

> the latest possible moment

As in:

> It is high time that we should rise to change the government.” Seattle
>   Times 2018

and

> It’s high time she made it over the wire. New York Times 2018

and

I see no reason one cannot open statements/writings with such.  The context, the audience etc. matter. Formal or informal usages are acceptable to this AmE speaker.

Comment: Can you go into more depth about the formality / informality of the idiom, since that seems to be the crux of the question.

Answer (score 2):

For examples of its use in a formal context, "high time" is used in the King James version of the Bible:

> Now it is **high time** to awake out of sleep - *[Rom. xiii. 11](https://biblehub.com/kjv/romans/13-11.htm)*

and by the US Secretary of State in a declaration against Saddam Hussein:

> It is **high time** that the international community tell Saddam Hussein and his regime that this is not an issue of negotiation with the U.N. about obligations that they undertook in 1991.  - *[Condoleezza Rice](http://transcripts.cnn.com/TRANSCRIPTS/0209/08/le.00.html)*

Comment: Tnx but your examples do not follow the "past tense" structure.

Comment: @MahmoudMoravej I disagree. This answer is thoroughly appropriate to the question you asked.

Comment: @MahmoudMoravej The tense is irrelevant to the formality of the phrase *it is high time*. Either you would use the phrase or not. What follows it is something separate.